# Убрать заголовки «X-PHP-Script» и «X-PHP-Filename» при отправке почты с сайта

Tags: php, email

Перестала на ящик в яндексе приходить почта с пары сайтов.
Сервис mail-tester.com показывает проблему, мол почта отправляется через PHP_SCRIPT:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Т.е. проблема вот в этих заголовках:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
вроде раньше меньше баллов отнималось..

Как сделать так, чтобы при отправке письма не было этих заголовков «X-PHP-Script» и «X-PHP-Filename»?
Отправляю письма через движки drupal7 или webasyst, или с помощью библиотеки PHPMailer. Т.е. там используется php функция mail().

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24393846/removing-the-php-mailer-sent-header

Comment: @KoVadim Добавил в PHPMailer строчку с $mail->SMTPDebug = false; не изменилось ничего, заголовки так же есть..

Comment: я поискал по исходникам PHPMailer, и там нет таких заголовков. Но рядом было найдено issue https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/issues/2169 - и там написано, что это проблема mail.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22428851/how-to-remove-headers-revealing-system-info-when-sending-mail-in-php 
вот тут еще есть решение изменить настройки пхп чтобы было mail.add_x_header = Off; expose_php = Off.  add_x_header - у меня и был off. Выставил expose_php в Off, но снова все так же.